# Installing Windows 7 on VM VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox

I got this error message when I was trying to install Windows 7 on VM VirtualBox:

```
VM: Raising runtime error 'HostMemoryLow' (fFlags=0x2)
00:03:39.566757 AssertLogRel F:\tinderbox\win-4.3\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3     \VMM.cpp(1756) int __cdecl VMMR3EmtRendezvous(struct VM *,unsigned int,int    (__cdecl *)(struct VM *,struct VMCPU *,void *),void *):  !pVCpu->vmm.s.fInRendezvous
00:03:39.566781 Console: VM runtime error: fatal=false, errorID=HostMemoryLow message="Unable to allocate and lock memory. The virtual machine will be paused. Please close applications to free up memory or close the VM"
 00:03:39.566913 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'GURU_MEDITATION'.
 00:04:49.029767 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6} aComponent={Console} aText={Invalid machine state GuruMeditation when checking if the guest entered the ACPI mode)}, preserve=false
 00:04:55.063001 Console::powerDown(): A request to power off the VM has been issued (mMachineState=Stopping, InUninit=0)
 00:04:55.063001 Changing the VM state from 'GURU_MEDITATION' to 'POWERING_OFF'.
```

How can I complete the installation?

Comment: How much RAM is installed in the physical machine, and how much RAM have you allocated to the VM?  64-bit or 32-bit Windows 7 install?

Comment: 2 Gb RAM in Physical machine and 1 Gb i have allocated to VM, 32-bit windows 7

Comment: Do I have to allocate more or less Gbits  to  windows 7  on the VM VirtualBox

Comment: hmmmm, perhaps there is not enough memory on your host?  Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to allocate less memory (512 MB or whatever is possible) to the virtual machine. Try to free up more memory by closing some applications on the host machine that you're not using.

Comment: You're probably getting down-voted because this is a pretty weak answer.  You offer no explanation as to what the error means, or why your solution will help avoid it. this seems more like a suggestion comment rather than a definitive answer.

Comment: Question is not "what does this error mean?", but "How can I complete the installation?". I answered it, so why do you demand more?

Comment: Accurate answer although lacks explanation. Here's an up-vote to neutralize that negative.

Answer (score -2):

After several tries I found the answer: I have allocated about 800 Mb to VM and it works well now.